# "On Behalf Of" for SOAP services

Tags: web-services, soap

We are altering our webservices to require an application using them to provide information on the real user who is requesting the data. For REST services we are implementing this using an X-On-Behalf-Of HTTP header. Should we do the same for SOAP services? Or better put it in a custom SOAP request header? What are best practices in this area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though answer depends on internals of your application architecture and other design principals you might have followed.

> Its ideal to keep Rest/SOAP services implemented the almost same security Model, hence if you're planing to use `X-On-Behalf-Of' HTTP, it make sense to use same in case of SOAP services as well.

But, in case of SOAP it you're using WS-Security or some Kind of Custom SOAP Header to do Authentication/Authorization in every SOAP Call, it makes more sense to Modify SOAP header itself to get the additional `On-Behalf-Of' detail as well rather then Custom HTTP Header for`X-on-behalf-of`

Refer [Message 2 - WS-Trust Token Exchange Request](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2003/06/24/ws-trust.html) section for more details.

Comment: We are indeed using WS-Security SOAP headers to do the authentication

Comment: OK, so It makes more sense to add 'On-Behalf-Of' details in SOAP WS-Security Header as well, it will keep all your Security details at single place, instead some on WS-Security Header and On-Behalf-Of in HTTP headers, so second part of my answer is more relevant and obvious in my opinion in your case.